# How prepared will I be to play Arkham Horror after reading just the Rulebook?

Tags: arkham-horror

I noticed the faq files for Arkham Horror are very large and are partially incorporated into the revised printing, but will I simply be doing some things outright wrong unless I review the faq first?  Will it be sufficient to use the faq as a reference and expect certain aspects of the game will be confusing and prompt me to look up the appropriate section?

Comment: While I agree with @recognizer (+1ed), I played the game a bunch before I knew of the FAQ. If it bothers you to relearn a bunch of rules, you probably want to follow it closely, but if you can take "Oh, I've been doing that wrong", then I'd say don't stress. I didn't answer because I actually feel like the answer is based somewhat upon how to play games and treat rules. My "answer" is not for everyone. Honestly, I reread the FAQ from time to time and find things I've done wrong. I think it unlikely one would remember every bit of the FAQ and the references to it are a little more scattered.

Comment: I personally am often content with giving myself 4 or 5 run-throughs of a game taking small stabs at clarification but not terribly long before making a quick ruling and writing down the question to research later and ask here on B&CG if necessary. It sometimes feels like the fastest way to reach full understanding in the medium term.

Comment: If you're really worried, you can do a solo game (maybe with two investigators) to make sure you figure out the obvious stuff before you try playing with a group of less patient people.

Comment: @Joey You (and people like you) should be fine then [in my opinion]=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing would be to learn the rules from someone who's very proficient in them, from their own experience playing. My experience, however, consisted of learning to play Arkham Horror with four friends who were all new to the game as well. In that case, I would suggest that anyone who has not played the game before at least attempt to read the entire rulebook and FAQ first.

If you don't have at least one person participating who's very conversant in the rules, then you'll probably be referring to the rulebook a LOT, not just checking the FAQ for clarifications. Note how long the ["short" version of a quick reference guide in this answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5415/what-do-you-recommend-putting-in-an-arkham-horror-quick-reference-sheet/5416#5416) is. It's pretty hard to explain the game concisely, and a lot of complications arise beyond the basic rules of the game. Naturally, the FAQ derives from those complications, and simply being aware of which characters, cards, etc have clarifications written about them will help you know whether to consult the rulebook or FAQ while playing. Don't expect to remember everything you read, there's just so much, but do everything you can to make it easier to refer to later.

If you consult some other questions on Arkham Horror, you'll see some comments about the importance of at least [one player having the expertise to guide other new players](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1864/arkham-horror-dominant-personality-issue/1877#1877). If you don't have that one expert player, then simply reading the rules AND the FAQ may not be enough to get everything right when first playing. So in short, you should read everything, and still be okay with the expectation that it may take a while to get it all right!

Comment: I mostly agree, but I'd look at it a bit differently. If no one has played before, you'll still have a good game, you'll just have to look at the rulebook (or possibly a cheat sheet/reference guide) a decent amount. Worst case, you'll realize later that you got a couple little things wrong. That seems totally fine, unless you're playing with really impatient people - in which case Arkham Horror probably wasn't the right game in the first place!