# Where can I find a list of cooperative "beat the game" games?

Tags: recommendations, cooperation

I know of Pandemic and I remember having played a game about mountain climbing where the goal was to as a team climb the mountain and get back down safely but there must be more of these games where one play as a team rather than against each other. Where can I find a good list of such games?

Comment: "Flash Point: Fire Rescue" & "Zombicide" are two good ones

Comment: [What cooperative board games are there that I could safely play with my wife?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/9/50)

Comment: By the way, I think this question is really just an instance of, "Where can I find a list of games that meet specific criteria?"

Comment: @AndrewVandever I totally agree. However without a link to what you mean with that comment I have a hard time understanding what you mean... Is it missing some tag for that or what point are you trying to make?

Comment: So for example you could check here: http://boardgamegeek.com/tag/cooperative. @sitnaltax's answer is really good. My point is that 95% of it is also applicable to the questions, "Where can I find a list of 2-player games?", "...worker placement games?", "...deck building games?", "...Lovecraft-themed games?", etcetera. So this is a very specific question with an answer that is very general. I would also say that the identify-this-game tag seems to generally consist of questions for which the answer is very specific (http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

BoardGameGeek's [advanced search](http://boardgamegeek.com/advsearch/boardgame) can be used to find a large list of co-op games. You can then sort or filter this list in several helpful ways. This form is a little bit daunting, but powerful. From the "Board Game Mechanic" list, select "Co-operative play". You will probably also want to check the "Filter Expansions" box and, if you are interested in widely available games, a minimum rating and minimum number of user ratings such as 200. ([Here is a direct link which will perform that query for you.](http://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&advsearch=1&objecttype=boardgame&q=&include%5Bdesignerid%5D=&geekitemname=&include%5Bpublisherid%5D=&geekitemname=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmin%5D=&range%5Byearpublished%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bminage%5D%5Bmax%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmin%5D=6&floatrange%5Bavgrating%5D%5Bmax%5D=10&range%5Bnumvoters%5D%5Bmin%5D=200&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmin%5D=&floatrange%5Bavgweight%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bnumweights%5D%5Bmin%5D=&nopropertyids%5B%5D=1042&range%5Bminplayers%5D%5Bmax%5D=&range%5Bmaxplayers%5D%5Bmin%5D=&playerrangetype=normal&range%5Bplayingtime%5D%5Bmax%5D=&propertyids%5B%5D=2023&B1=Submit)) You might want to sort the results by Geek Rating, which penalizes games that have fewer ratings, or by Average Rating, which does not.

Comment: An excellent answer. I would like to point out, however, that this search does have some false positives, such as _Betrayal at House on the Hill_ -- the game is co-op at the start, but once the Haunt begins, the game is almost guaranteed to become one-vs-many or a free-for-all (depending on the specific Haunt that occurs, which is random with some weighting). I say "almost" guaranteed, because IIRC there are one or two Haunts which maintain the co-op aspect of the game... but _Betrayal_ 2nd edition has 50 different Haunts.

Comment: True. It is interesting (and perhaps a testament to the fuzziness of definitions) that Betrayal, Scotland Yard, and Shadows over Camelot have the "Co-operative" mechanism tagged, while Letters from Whitechapel and Battlestar Galactica do not.

Answer (score 13):

Check out http://boardgamegeek.com/ and play with the advanced search feature. You'll find everything you need. It probably will be a better source of knowledge than your local game store, as BGG is not limited to what it has on the shelves and does not try to sell you something.

(btw,  the game you played was most probably K2)

The link to [boardgamegeek for coop games](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamemechanic/2023/co-operative-play).